# Jquery, select children class inside each loop

Tags: jquery

I have a variable number of divs in the page, and i need to create an incremental id to add to the divs. This works already, now, within the divs i have also a button that needs to have the same id as the parent...
this is what i did, but i don't know why it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="article-container">
    This is the text of article 1<br/>
    With some html tags like this <span>SPAN</span>, this <b>Bold text</b>, some <i>Italic</i> and some <a href="www.google.co.uk">Links</a>
</div>
<button class="btn">
    Copy Article
</button>
<hr>
<div class="article-container">
    This is the text of article 1<br/>
    With some html tags like this <span>SPAN</span>, this <b>Bold text</b>, some <i>Italic</i> and some <a href="www.google.co.uk">Links</a>
</div>
<button class="btn">
    Copy Article
</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
var parentDivs = $(".article-container");

$(parentDivs).each(function (i) {
    var index = i + 1;
    $(this).attr('id', index);
    $('button.btn', this ).attr('id', index);
})
```

**EDIT:**
As mentioned a couple of times below, the button is not inside the div, so this is why is not picking up the id (that i'm going to change with a prefix, thanks for notice that)

I moved the button inside the div and now it's working properly.
Thanks

Comment: Giving two elements the same id (buttons/divs) is a bad practice. Consider prefixing them.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I'm going to change the code with a prefix on the ids then

Comment: Multiple elements with the same id is not permitted. And also, i don't know what you are doing on this line: `$('button.btn', this)...`

Comment: according to another stackoverflow answer, it should be a shorthand for $(this).children('button.btn').attr('id', index);

Comment: `button.btn` is not a child of `.article-container` in your HTML. You may want to use `.siblings()` or `.next()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

1. button is not the child of div

So either move the button inside the div or use `next()` selector.

2. Assigning same id to 2 elements is bad practice.

For e.g.

```
<button class="btn" id="btn">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn">Button 2</button>
```

With above $("#btn") will always return the first button.

Comment: i didn't notice that! moving the buttons inside the div make the above code working.

Comment: This should be the answer. The second part is most important. You should provide an example to support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
    var parentDivs = $(".article-container");

```
$(parentDivs).each(function (i) {
    var index = i + 1;
    $(this).attr('id', index);
    $(this).find('button.btn').attr('id', "btn"+index);
})
```

**Edit**

You mentioned that buttons are children of the article-container div right? So I corrected the HTML as well. This should work.

```js
var parentDivs = $(".article-container");

    $(parentDivs).each(function (i) {
        var index = i + 1;
        $(this).attr('id', index);
        $(this).find('button.btn').attr('id', "btn"+index);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article-container">
    This is the text of article 1<br/>
    With some html tags like this <span>SPAN</span>, this <b>Bold text</b>, some <i>Italic</i> and some <a href="www.google.co.uk">Links</a>
<button class="btn">
    Copy Article
</button>
</div>

<hr>
<div class="article-container">
    This is the text of article 1<br/>
    With some html tags like this <span>SPAN</span>, this <b>Bold text</b>, some <i>Italic</i> and some <a href="www.google.co.uk">Links</a>
<button class="btn">
    Copy Article
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parentDivs` with `.next()` to target the proper button, and not re-use IDs.

```js
var parentDivs = $(".article-container");

$(parentDivs).each(function (i) {
    var index = i + 1;
    $(this).attr('id', 'a'+index);
    $(this).next('button.btn').attr('id', 'b'+index);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article-container">
    This is the text of article 1<br/>
    With some html tags like this <span>SPAN</span>, this <b>Bold text</b>, some <i>Italic</i> and some <a href="www.google.co.uk">Links</a>
</div>
<button class="btn">
    Copy Article
</button>
<hr>
<div class="article-container">
    This is the text of article 1<br/>
    With some html tags like this <span>SPAN</span>, this <b>Bold text</b>, some <i>Italic</i> and some <a href="www.google.co.uk">Links</a>
</div>
<button class="btn">
    Copy Article
</button>
```

Note that I also prefix the ID with an alphabetic character as numeric IDs are problematic for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line

`$('button.btn', this ).attr('id', index);`

to:

`$(this).next('button.btn').attr('id', index);`

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/czh16dd5/

Comment: if you want to assign same value to button as div then use class because you can apply same class to number of elements and as Nikhil said is meant for single element.